# Проблема центровки блока

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, почему на разных пк, блок на сайте отцентрирован по разному? Т.е у меня блок находится по центру, но допустим я делаю скриншот страницы(с помощью различных онлайн сервисов), то там блок находится правее, на ноутбуке тоже самое. Как в таком случае  отцентрировать элемент?

```css
#SECTION_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 700px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 676px 624px;
  transform-origin: 676px 624px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background: rgb(14, 17, 37) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  margin: 0px -20px;
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 70px 0px;
}


/*#SECTION_1*/

#SECTION_1:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SECTION_1:after*/

#SECTION_1:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SECTION_1:before*/

#DIV_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 1108px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 1170px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 585px 554px;
  transform-origin: 585px 554px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 9px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 350px;
  margin-top: -60px
}


/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  content: '"' '"';
  display: table;
  height: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_2:after*/

#DIV_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  content: '"' '"';
  display: table;
  height: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_2:before*/

#H2_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 44px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 1140px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 570px 22px;
  transform-origin: 570px 22px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 700 normal 40px / 44px montserrat, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H2_3*/

#H2_3:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 700 normal 40px / 44px montserrat, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H2_3:after*/

#H2_3:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 700 normal 40px / 44px montserrat, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H2_3:before*/

#DIV_4 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 925px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1220px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 610px 462.5px;
  transform-origin: 610px 462.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 75px -40px 0px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*#DIV_4*/

#DIV_4:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  content: '""';
  display: none;
  height: 20%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgba(0, 43, 75, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 43, 75) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:after*/

#DIV_4:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px "roboto slab", "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:before*/
```

```html
<section id="SECTION_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">

    <h2 id="H2_3">
      Roadmap
    </h2>

    <div id="DIV_4">
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">
          <div id="DIV_7">
            <span id="SPAN_8">Q1 2018</span> <span id="SPAN_9"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_10">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_11" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_12">
            <span id="SPAN_13">Establish first Crypto-Mine</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_14">
            <svg id="svg_15">
                            <use id="use_16">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_17">
          <div id="DIV_18">
            <span id="SPAN_19">Q2/Q3 2018</span> <span id="SPAN_20"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_21">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_22" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_23">
            <span id="SPAN_24">Launch Ponos-Mining Platform.<br>First dividend payouts.</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_25">
            <svg id="svg_26">
                            <use id="use_27">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_28">
          <div id="DIV_29">
            <span id="SPAN_30">Q3/Q4 2018</span> <span id="SPAN_31"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_32">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_33" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_34">
            <span id="SPAN_36">Launch Wallet platform, Vidulum.<br>



Expand total mining capacity by 25%.</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_37">
            <svg id="svg_38">
                            <use id="use_39">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_40">
          <div id="DIV_41">
            <span id="SPAN_42">Q2/Q3 2019</span> <span id="SPAN_43"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_44">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_45" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_46" style="width:300px; margin-left:-64px">
            Expand total mining capacity<br> by 50% from inception.


          </div>
          <div id="DIV_47">
            <svg id="svg_48">
                            <use id="use_49">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_50">
          <div id="DIV_51">
            <span id="SPAN_52">Q3/Q4 2019</span> <span id="SPAN_53"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_54">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_55" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_56">
            <span id="SPAN_58">Double mining capacity from inception.<br>



Launch marketplace platform, OneMarketStreet
                          </span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_59">
            <svg id="svg_60">
                            <use id="use_61">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_62" style="margin-left:420px">
          <div id="DIV_63">
            <span id="SPAN_64" style="margin-top:-280px">Q2 2020</span> <span id="SPAN_65"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_66">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_67" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_68" style="width:300px; left:-50px">Triple mining capacity from inception.
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_69">
            <svg id="svg_70">
                            <use id="use_71">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_72">
          <div id="DIV_73">
            <span id="SPAN_74" style="margin-top:-280px; margin-left:434px">Q3 2020</span> <span id="SPAN_75" style="margin-left:500px"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_76" style="margin-left:515px">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_77" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_78" style="margin-left:434px">
            Establish VRTM's fungibility.
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_79">
            <svg id="svg_80">
                            <use id="use_81">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DIV_82">
          <div id="DIV_83">
            <span id="SPAN_84" style="margin-top:-280px; margin-left:434px">FUTURE</span>
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_86" style="margin-left:515px">
            <img src="img/check.svg" alt="" id="IMG_87" />
          </div>
          <div id="DIV_88">

          </div>
          <div id="DIV_91">
            <svg id="svg_92">
                            <use id="use_93">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>









      </div>
      <div id="DIV_240">
        <div id="DIV_241">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Если сложно добавить код HTML и стили к вопросу, то ответ такой:

```css
.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.square.-middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@supports (display: -webkit-box) or (display: -moz-box) or (display: -webkit-flex) or (display: -moz-flex) or (display: flex) {
  .square.-middle {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square -middle"></div>
```

Но в отсутствии кода в вопросе, так же не исключены факты что родительский блок не на всю ширину экрана и данный блок центрируется относительно максимальной ширины родителя

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/319868)

Comment: @Dmitriy, почему не является?

Comment: @Qwertiy Так автор вопроса никакого кода не привел, а в таком виде на вопрос ответить невозможно. Так-то да, таким образом отцентрировать элемент можно, но до появления авторского кода это будет гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @Dmitriy, а по-моему, раз отцентрировать можно, значит ответ, если вопросу не противоречит

Comment: А потом автор опубликует код, и с некоторой вероятностью окажется, что противоречит. А неправильный ответ так и будет болтаться, ведь проверка показала, что ответ хороший... P. S. И вообще, другой ответ мне больше нравится.

Comment: @Dmitriy, изменил ответ, но он был так же плох как и тот что вам понравился...

Answer (score 0):

Для `#DIV_2` задайте `margin: -60px auto 0;`. Свойство `auto` отцентрует ваш блок.
И уберите все `transform` чтобы не было скролла горизонтального.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй родителю задать

```
.block { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/319882)

Comment: @Air, почему не содержится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Уверен, что процентов на 75 данный ответ поможет... Но тут большое `НО`,  черт знает что там у автора в разметке и как все реализовано...  Так что это не ответ, а предположение...  Ни вопрос ни ответ не несут ни какой  пользы...

Comment: @Air, как раз ответ несёт - так можно отцентрировать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты модератор, тебе видней... Но я останусь при своем мнении...